# Spring Boot, Angular2, Cross-origin

Tags: spring-mvc, angular, cross-domain

I have a web-server in Spring Boot. I can send HTTP requests to it and get answers from tools like Send HTTP. I also have a web site based on Angular2 whoich works too. Part of the functionality must include HTTP requests from the Angular2 running in Chrome to the Spring Boot server. Every time I do it I have an error in Chrome console:

> *XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'URL Server'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'URL Client' is therefore not allowed access*.

I put into Spring server @CrossOrigin in all places where it makes sense: before @Controller, @RequestMapping, @GetMapping, but it did not help. What I am missing and how to overcome?
Great thanks, a bit desperate, Levi

Answer (score 1):

```
@Bean
   public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
            config.setAllowCredentials(true);
            config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
            config.addAllowedHeader("*");
            config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
            config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
            config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
            config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
            config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
            return new CorsFilter(source);
        }
```

try this it works for me !

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("<<MAPPING>>").allowedOrigins("<<ORIGINS>>");
            }
        };
    }
```

Please go through below tutorial and try with alternate option if still not working :

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Update 1:

As updated by @Levi

```
    import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration; //+ more public class RestConfiguration { 

    @Bean public CorsFilter corsFilter() { 

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource(); CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration(); 
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
     config.addAllowedOrigin("*"); 
    config.addAllowedHeader("*"); 
    config.addAllowedMethod("*"); 
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
     return new CorsFilter(source); } 

}
```

Comment: I tried all that appears in the manual and your recommendation too, and still have the problem.

Comment: The following succeeded:
`import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration; //+ more
public class RestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true); 
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }   
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CQRSFilter for your application and set that CORSFilter in your spring boot configuration class.

What you have to do is

1> Create your own CQRSFilter that implements Filter

2>You should add code as below in your filter

```
@Component
public class CORSFilter implements Filter{
static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CORSFilter.class);

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

public void destroy() {}
}
```

3> Place your filter in spring configuration file

```
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
      .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)

  }
 }
```

Comment: Your answer seems promising, because it is the header that is missing. Thanks, but can you, please, add some details? I do not understand where I write 
`response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");`
Also which spring configuration file meant, sorry for being so dense.

Comment: I have added some relevant code.You need to add your own additional configuration if needed. And if you find it helpful please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need setup a proxy to backend as is described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/d22e9ae73763923980fc1e59cfb2a0bf255b98d8/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md).

1) Create file proxy.conf.json (next to package.json) with the content

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

2) Edit start script in package.json

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```

3) Run with

```
npm start
```